# java file input pair of numbers linkedlist

Tags: java, data-structures, file-io, linked-list

I've been looking around and can't seem to find the best answer for the problem that I'm doing.
I currently have a .txt file that I need to read in, it looks a little something like this:

```
1,10
5,16
2,7
4,12
3,19
```

Now I'm supposed to create a linked list which is fine, my biggest problem is I'm not sure how
to get it so that it will read in the pair, the first number represents a process ID and the second is the amount of time it takes before termination. Would I want to do a parseInt to the string and grab each one separately before and after the comma, or would there be an easier way at doing this. We can't use ArrayLists either.

```
Scanner fin = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
 while(fin.hasNext()){
 int s = fin.nextInt();
```

This is what I have got so far for reading the file in

Comment: I'm needing to reopen this topic. I'm having issues on the LinkedList and it only displaying up to 4,12. It will take in all the inputs but only display to the 4th Node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
Scanner fin = new Scanner(new FileReader(file);
String pattern = ",";
fin.useDelimiter(pattern);
while (fin.hasNext()) {
    String s = fin.nextLine();
    String[] arr = s.split(pattern);
    int processID = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
    int time = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
}
```